# No resource identifier found for attribute 'largeScreens' in package 'android'

Tags: android-layout

I keep getting the error 
"No resource identifier found for attribute 'largeScreens' in package 'android'"
I get this error for all of the difrent sizes of screen.

is it because my code block is set wrong?

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

<supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
              android:smallScreens="true" 
              android:normalScreens="true" 
              android:largeScreens="true" 
              android:xlargeScreens="true"
              android:anyDensity="true" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your project build target (in Eclipse, right click on the project name in Package Explorer and select Properties) from `1.5` to `1.6` and rebuild.

Comment: thanks but also i added uses-sdk to androisManifest.xml to solve this error