# No resource identifier found for attribute 'exitFadeDuration' in package 'android'

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I got the following error in android project in eclipse:

`error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'exitFadeDuration' in package 'android'`

Similar questions are solved by changing the build target ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6446300/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-largescreens-in-package-android), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260686/no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-showasaction-in-package-android)). The minimum sdk level is 10. So, my build target is Android 2.3.3 and even when the Android version is changed to 4.0.3 the error persists.

Answer (score 1):

In ADT (Eclipse), on your project's right-click menu choose: **Android Tools --> Add Support Library** accept, and you should be done.

Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11814061/errorres-menu-main-xml15-error-no-resource-identifier-found-for-attribute-a), which worked for me, even if it refers to another attribute.