# Error:res\menu\main.xml:15: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionProviderClass' in package 'android'

Tags: android, eclipse, error-handling, compiler-errors

okay, im making an application for tablets and i get this error with my actiobar/menu xml
my target and minsdk versions are both at 11 api.
I dont know whats the problem!!!!
Heres the error:

res\menu\main.xml:15: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'actionProviderClass' in package 'android'

Any Help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ActionProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ActionProvider.html) class was added in API 14. However it is supported, to an extent, in the backwards compatibility libraries. Make sure that you have added these to your project.

In Eclipse, right-click your project in the **Package Explorer** window -> navigate to **Android Tools** -> select **Add Support Library**